# XNA 4.0 Post-Processing Libraries?

Tags: xna-4.0, post-processing

Are there any free XNA 4.0 post-processing libraries that are easy to hook into projects? I am looking specifically for a glow effect (although anything is great), and I should also mention that I'm using the Reach profile.

EDIT: I should add that I'm not concerned about the Windows phone, because it can't support custom shaders.

Comment: Have you tried the bloom postprocess sample? http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/bloom

Comment: That's a brilliant example. I haven't gone into the code yet but it's for the Reach profile and looks great. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/tutorials/) is a lot of tutorials on Post Processing.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to mark this as the answer because it's not really an answer to the question, but this is another excellent resource, and much appreciated.

Comment: Thats fair enough, but I don't think that you'll find a Post Processing library on its own as it has a lot to do with how you are rendering your scene.